# can we give input to system by programmatically instead of using keyboard in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Example 
./calculate.sh
Enter A
10(user entered using keyboard)
**(Instead)**
./calculate.sh
Enter A
10(with out using keyboard we give this input to console)

NOTE: don't print the value to console,we gave to give the input to console as our predefined value

is it possible?

Comment: can please mention one example how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it, listing few that i know of:

1. Input/Output Redirection(http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/chap_05.html)
2. Pipes(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-pipes-filters.htm)
3. Then there are advanced programming mechanism grouped under IPC(InterProcess Communication) which can be also used